# Omit time in datetime type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to compare both dates in 2 columns SHIFTA_Start and SHIFTA_End.
However each column contains both date and time fields,
I just want to compare the dates, and omit the time.

Image of Date and Time in Datetime Datatype:

[image]

Comment: `CAST` them to `DATE`.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? `CAST(... AS DATE)` will work form 2008 onwards

Comment: I am using mssql 2014! @raj

Comment: You could cast to date as the answers suggest, but you should take into consideration that this will prevent Sql server to use indexes on these columns you you are casting in the where clause. If you don't have indexes on these columns, or your table doesn't contain many rows, it's insignificant, but if you have 10,000 rows or more indexed on these columns you might see a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can `CAST` them to `DATE`

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SHIFTA_Start AS DATE),
    CAST(SHIFTA_End AS DATE)
```

If you're not allowed to `CAST` to `DATE` due to having a lower version of SQL Server, you can use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', SHIFTA_Start), '19000101'),
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', SHIFTA_End), '19000101')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` them `DATE` to compare

```
CAST(SHIFTA_Start AS DATE) ,
CAST(SHIFTA_End AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't fussed about the data type the easiest way is probably to CAST the value to a DATE data type.

However, if you want to keep the `DATETIME` data type but just flatten out the time portion my preferred method is to use DATEADD & DATEDIFF from a fixed point.

E.g.:

```
DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, DateField), 0)
```

This takes the number of days between date `0` and the DateField and then adds that back to date `0` effectively removing the time portion. You can also alter the interval portion of the DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions to flatten the value to the month or year. Or add a fixed integer to the DATEDIFF value to get a certain date in the future (without the time).

E.g.:

```
DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, DateField) + 1, 0)
```

Will return the tomorrow relative to `DateField` but set to 00:00:00.